# How to stay on tab when refresh page in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jsf

Pages are changing without loading (thanks to jQuery), but after reloading page they always go back to main page (main.jsp). Is it possible to stay on page I choose after refreshing?

JSP file (main.jsp):

```
<ul>
    if ((loginBean.getStatus() != "") && (loginBean.getStatus() != null)) {
%>
<li><a href=main.jsp><h:outputText value="#{kom.glowna}"/></a></li>
<li><a id="about_us" href="#about">O nas</a></li>
    <%
        if (loginBean.getStatus().equals("admin")) {
    %>
<li><a id="show_accounts" href="#accounts"><h:outputText value="#{kom.konta}"/></a></li>
<li><a id="register_all" href="#register"><h:outputText value="#{kom.zarejestruj}"/></a></li>
<li><a id="delete_account" href="#delete"><h:outputText value="#{kom.usun}"/></a></li>
    <%
    } else if (loginBean.getStatus().equals("klient")) {
    %>
<li><a id="zapis_na_wizyte" href="#visit"><h:outputText value="#{kom.wizyta}"/></a></li>
<li><a id="add_animal" href="#animal"><h:outputText value="#{kom.zwierze}"/></a></li>
<%
} else if (loginBean.getStatus().equals("lekarz")) {
%>
<li><a id="patients" href="#patients"><h:outputText value="#{kom.pacjenci}"/></a></li>
    <%
        }
    %>
<li><a id="my_account" href="#account"><h:outputText value="#{kom.konto}"/></a></li>
<li>
    <h:form>
        <h:commandLink action="#{loginBean.logout}" ><h:outputText value="#{kom.wyloguj}"/></h:commandLink>
    </h:form>
</li>
<%
} else {
%>    
<li>
    <h:form>
        <h:commandLink value="Wróć do strony głównej." action="#{loginBean.logout}"><h:outputText value="#{kom.wroc}"/></h:commandLink>
    </h:form>
</li>
<%
    }
%>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
$().ready(function()
{
    $("#about_us").click(function()
    {
        $("article").load("about.jsp");
    });
    $("#show_accounts").click(function()
    {
        $("article").load("showAccounts.jsp");
    });
    $("#register_all").click(function()
    {
        $("article").load("registerAll.jsp");
    });
    $("#delete_account").click(function()
    {
        $("article").load("deleteAccount.jsp");
    });
    $("#zapis_na_wizyte").click(function()
    {
        $("article").load("showAnimal.jsp");
    });
    $("#add_animal").click(function()
    {
        $("article").load("addAnimal.jsp");
    });
    $("#patients").click(function()
    {
        $("article").load("pacjenci.jsp");
    });
    $("#my_account").click(function()
    {
        $("article").load("account.jsp");
    });
});
```

I'll be gratefull for any help.

Comment: side-note, it's recommended to NOT use `$().ready(function`, instead, you should be using `$(document).ready(function` or `$(function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to use `hash`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onhashchange for more infos.

The idea is to use this event to handle when hash changed. This event is also sent when you load your page which contain a hash (e.g. yoursite.com/main.jsp#my_account).

To retreive the current hash, use `window.location.hash`.

Another way to do it is to use `History.js`.

See https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/

Answer (score -1):

you could use a cookie (or a session) to save the page. There is a jquery plugin to manage cookies here: http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/